# About form closing at runtime in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, formclosing

I have two forms named `frmRegistration` & `frmMain` in my project in *c#*.

I have set `frmRegistration` as my *start form*.
User enters data in the `frmRegistration` form & presses *submit* button to get registered. Then, I want to close `frmRegistration` form & show `frmMain` form to the user.
I'm trying this by using `Dispose()` method of the `frmRegistration`. But, when I use this method, *it disposes all my application execution* because `frmRegistration` is the startup form.

I don't want this to happen. Can anyone solve this problem?

thanks.

Comment: why didn't you use form.close() method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Show()` and `Hide()` methods.

```
    private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      ...
      var frm = new frmMain();
      frm.Location = this.Location;
      frm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
      frm.Show();
      this.Hide();
    }
```

**UPDATE:**
If you don't want to have frmRegistration in memory, start your program in main form and add this in your MainForm's `Shown` event:

```
    var frm = new frmRegistration();
    frm.Location = this.Location;
    frm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
    frm.FormClosing += delegate { this.Show(); };
    frm.Show();
    this.Hide();
```

Now you can just close the registration form and automatically get back to main form.

Comment: the problem with this approach is that you always keep frmRegistraion in memory, and I don't think its necessary.

Comment: AtoMerZ: I agree, `frmRegistration` is the one which should be instantiated inside main form. That makes more sense. For example, there could be a login/logout menu item in the main form, which would also show an instance of `frmRegistration`. And the way Kamyar suggests, closing the main form will not close the `frmRegistration`, it will just remain hidden, unless there is a listener to main forms `FormClosing` event (and that is just unnecessary extra work).

Comment: i've tried your second code. I've written the above code in frmMain's Load() event & i've set the frmMain as my start up form in Program.cs . . When i've used this code that time my frmMain form is shown & my frmRegistration form is get hidden.But i'm not getting what i want. I want to execute my frmRegistration form first & after clicking on submit button i want to close that form permanently & i want to open my frmMain form. do you know anything about this

Comment: I used your code. It shows the required result but the frmMain form is shown for 1sec & after that it gets hidden & then it opens frmRegistration. And if my frmMain form is at maximize size & frmRegistration is at normal size then it not looks good. but thanks for reply.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting frmMain as start up form and hiding it initialy, show frmRegistration, do what you have to do, and Dispose it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also change you `Program.cs` main class with the `Main()` function to start `frmRegistration` and after positive `DialogResult` or another check it will then start with `frmMain` - as your main form and message loop.

Comment: That would work, but would bring additional complications if OP would decide to implement login/logout functionality once the main form is already started.

Answer (score 0):

At least there are two options:
1.Turn your Start up form into a singleton
  When you need to hide it, call it's hide method

2.Have new different startup form, call it MainApp form or whatever, have it set to invisible, the you can do what ever you like with the other non-startup forms.